# How do I use alert() for errors?

Tags: jquery

How do I alert() an error when my server code returns false?

```
  $("#editme1").editInPlace({
    url: 'server.php',
    error_sink: function(editme1, errorString) { alert(errorString); } <----Maybe this?
  });
```

Comment: pls specify wat is ur need? pls use ajax to get value from server.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do exactly , if you are using ajax to call server side you can do in the error block. see the documentation here
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`error` callback](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/source/browse/trunk/lib/jquery.editinplace.js#85), like this:

```
$("#editme1").editInPlace({
  url: 'server.php',
  error: function(xhr) { alert("Server error: " + xhr.responseText); }
});
```

Unfortunately the author didn't do a very good job here, [he ignored the other very useful parameter `error` parameters](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/source/browse/trunk/lib/jquery.editinplace.js#495) on the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) error callback (`textStatus` and `errorThrown`).

So instead of using his `error` callback at all I'd use the global [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) handler, for example:

```
$(document).ajaxError(xhr, options, error) {
  alert("An error occured when fetching content: " + error);
});
```

Then don't specify anything in the plugin options for this:

```
$("#editme1").editInPlace({ url: 'server.php' });
```